# Too many or too few context switches undesirable for computer system?

Tags: context-switch

I would like to know why too many or too few context switches would be undesirable in a computer system, would be really grateful if someone knew and could explain it to me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Too few: less (poor) real-time-alike behavior.

Too many: too much overhead spent in the OS's scheduler.